# Can I get a new U.S. passport sent to a U.S. consulate overseas after leaving the US with a different passport (dual citizenship)?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, dual-nationality, consulates

My child has dual US and German citizenship, we live in the US. Her US passport expired, the German one is still valid. Her new passport might not be ready in time for our travel plans. Judging from other answers on this site, we shouldn't have a problem leaving the US without her US passport, but coming back might be an issue. 
Is it possible to have the new US passport sent to Germany (I could pick it up at the consulate)? Or do I have to find a way to have someone else send the passport to Germany, or bring it there?

Comment: With confirmed travel plans, you should apply for an expedited passport while you're still here in the US.

Comment: Let's say (hypothetically :-P) that I only realized we had this problem last night and I have an appointment for an expedited passport on Thursday, and our flight leaves Sunday night, I'm guessing the expedited passport won't be fast enough to get it before we leave... which is why I'm wondering if they'll send it to Germany.

Comment: I don't know. Have you reviewed the US govt page on expedited passports? https://www.usa.gov/passport#item-34927 There are also private services (probably expensive) to do the legwork for you.

Comment: Yeah, I read that. We have more than 48 hours, but there's the weekend, too, and I have no idea how they handle that. There also doesn't seem to be a way to call them and ask someone, but I'm not far from the National Passport Center, so I guess I'll just show up to the appointment with everything needed and hope it works out. I'm not too worried about getting out of here without the passport since we still have the valid German passport, but I'm wondering how we'll get it in time for the flight back to the US.

Comment: The NPC *may* be able to arrange for the passport to go in a diplomatic courier pouch to a US consulate in Germany; it's worth asking. You would not want it sent via any postal service. You could take her German passport and your flight details with you to your appointment, only to show your impending departure and her valid travel document.

Comment: @Giorgio I've had passports sent by private services on a couple of occasions.  If it's lost, it's lost, and you get an emergency passport from the consulate.  But there's a very low chance of that happening.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone else ever has this sort of problem, here's what happened: 
The National Passport Center in Portsmouth managed to produce a passport for my kid in less than 24 hours, I could pick it up the next day. They were also the friendliest government bureaucracy people I have ever dealt with anywhere. I asked them if they would have sent it to the consulate in Frankfurt if it wouldn't have been fast enough, but they said they don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for returning to let us know what happened!

Comment: Please accept your own answer (the tick below the up and down votes) so we can close this. Thanks for telling us.